# Unable to Run cocos2d-x working copy projects after checking out from svn on mac

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am getting 20 errors while trying to run working copy after checking out from svn. All of these errors are related to libcoco2d/iOS.a file.
errors are :-

Libtool /Users/blacklight/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyGame-ejvovhtqcttutnaznyjrcgednhao/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2d\ iOS.a normal armv7
    cd /Users/blacklight/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.4/projects/MyGame-copy/cocos2d/build
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.1.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv7 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Users/blacklight/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyGame-ejvovhtqcttutnaznyjrcgednhao/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/blacklight/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.4/projects/MyGame-copy/cocos2d/build/../external/png/prebuilt/ios -L/Users/blacklight/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.4/projects/MyGame-copy/cocos2d/build/../external/jpeg/prebuilt/ios -L/Users/blacklight/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.4/projects/MyGame-copy/cocos2d/build/../external/tiff/prebuilt/ios -L/Users/blacklight/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.4/projects/MyGame-copy/cocos2d/build/../external/webp/prebuilt/ios -L/Users/blacklight/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.4/projects/MyGame-copy/cocos2d/build/../external/freetype2/prebuilt/ios -L/Users/blacklight/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.4/projects/MyGame-copy/cocos2d/build/../external/curl/prebuilt/ios -L/Users/blacklight/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.4/projects/MyGame-copy/cocos2d/build/../external/websockets/prebuilt/ios -L/Users/blacklight/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.4/projects/MyGame-copy/cocos2d/build/../external/chipmunk/prebuilt/ios -filelist /Users/blacklight/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyGame-ejvovhtqcttutnaznyjrcgednhao/Build/Intermediates/cocos2d_libs.build/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2d\ iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libcocos2d\ iOS.LinkFileList -lwebsockets -lcurl -lssl -framework Foundation -lpng -ljpeg -ltiff -lcrypto -lchipmunk -lwebp -lfreetype -o /Users/blacklight/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyGame-ejvovhtqcttutnaznyjrcgednhao/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2d\ iOS.a

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lwebsockets
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lwebsockets is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lcurl
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lcurl is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lssl
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lssl is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lpng
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lpng is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -ljpeg
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -ljpeg is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -ltiff
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -ltiff is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lcrypto
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lcrypto is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lchipmunk
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lchipmunk is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lwebp
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lwebp is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lfreetype
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lfreetype is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

Answer (score 0):

By default SVN doesnt include the prebuilt *.a files under the cocos2d/external folder. Re-copy the cocos2d folder and manually include those files.